# C++: Qt :libraries:screenGeometry()

Tags: qt, graphics, embedded

I am using a buildroot rootfile system on the raspberrypi3.

I can launch my qt application and it fills up the entire screen.  I have a popup window that I want to take up the full screen. On my main OS using screenGeometry() it fills up the entire monitor. On the pi one of two things happen

On a full size monitor  it pops up in a perfect square in the middle of the screen but does not take up the full monitor.

On the 7 inch screen, it is to big and fills up the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH=520

export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT=326

For anyone else struggling with this problem,do this and adjust as needed. I put it in a boot script before I launched my app.